# How do I access a folder which I can't sudo cd into?

Tags: shell, command-line, sudo, cd-command

I'm trying to change my directory to /boot/efi, but running `sudo cd /boot/efi` does nothing. I'm on fedora 23. Is there a more powerful command for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cd` is a shell builtin, and `sudo` only works with programs.

Try using either `su -` or `sudo -i` before changing directory. These will elevate your login session to that of the root user. Once finished making changes, make sure to type `exit` to return to being a normal user.

Comment: That works, thanks, but there's a file in there, grub.cfg, and i'm trying to copy it to my home folder, which works after doing sudo -i and using the cp command, however i don't have permission to open that file (it does work with sudo vim, but how do i change permissions on that file?)

Comment: `sudo chown username filename` should work.

Comment: Can i also keep root as the owner but add me as readwrite permissions?

Comment: `sudo chmod 666 filename` then to allow `rw-` permissions to everyone.

Comment: Cool, that works! I also looked it up and you can also do:

`sudo chown :frederik grub.cfg` to change the group

And `sudo chmod g+r grub.cfg` to give that group read permission

Thanks a lot!


`sudo chmod 640 grub.cfg` also works for changing the permissions (in this case rw for root and r for group, none for others.

Comment: You're welcome. Plenty of ways to do things.

Comment: Even on systems where `cd` is a real external command, this would not work as `sudo` would exit after executing the command.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without changing my user?  I would like to do a `git fetch` in the directory, but the SSH keys are only in the sudo user account, not in the root account.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to cd as super user:

```
sudo -s
cd directory
```

Comment: Please note that this does not maintain the environment.