# Run cd command with superuser priviledges

Tags: linux, sudo, directory, root

Is there a way to run the `cd` command with superuser privileges to gain access to directories that are owned by root? When I run `sudo cd <path>`, I get `sudo: cd: command not found`.

Comment: `cd` is a shell built-in, not an executable. `sudo` only works on executables. You can run `sudo /bin/cd <path>` but I don't think you'll get the results you're expecting.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/293871/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92989/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80346/117549  and others...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with running cd with sudo as another user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92989/trouble-with-running-cd-with-sudo-as-another-user)

Comment: Even if it did work, what would be the point of it? `sudo cd …` would start a root subshell, change that subshell's current directory, and then exit, returning to the non-root shell with the original current directory.